# How to download python 64 bit packages on 32 bit OS(Windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a system that is not connected with internet having 64 bit Windows-10 OS on it. I need to download all the packages for it Especially  "MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl" in 64 bit format. I tried using command "pip download MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-win64.whl" but it didnt worked. If someone knows the solution please share.

Comment: The title says "32 bit OS (Windows 10)", but the body of the post talks about "64 bit Windows-10 OS". Which one is it? Also, what exactly does "it didnt worked" mean? _How_ did it not work? What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: See i have a system that is having windows10- 64 bit OS intalled on it and have python 3.8.5 64 bit installed on it.

I need to download python packages for it since i cannot connect that system to internet. I have another system which is having windows 10 (32-bit) installed on it, where same version of python is also installed but it is in 32 bit format. 

Now i need to download  "MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-win64.whl" for my no internet system. How would i do so.?